# Delete OPENQUERY On Linked Server Fails When Variable Used As Condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**This works**

```
Delete OPENQUERY ([MyLinkedServer], 'SELECT * FROM db_from_sap_for_bi.VBRK')
```

**This works**

```
DECLARE @DateDailyUpdate as nvarchar(10)
set @DateDailyUpdate= (select DateDailyUpdate from tblDateFilter Where TableName='VBRK')

DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)
SELECT @TSQL = 'select * FROM OPENQUERY([MyLinkedServer],''Select * FROM db_from_sap_for_bi.VBRK WHERE FKDAT >= ''''' + @DateDailyUpdate + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

**This throws error**

```
SELECT @TSQL = 'Delete OPENQUERY([MyLinkedServer],''Select * FROM db_from_sap_for_bi.VBRK WHERE FKDAT >= ''''' + @DateDailyUpdate + ''''''')'
```

**Error Message**

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyLinkedServer"
> could not delete from table "Select * FROM db_from_sap_for_bi.VBRK
> WHERE FKDAT >= '20230930'". There was a recoverable, provider-specific
> error, such as an RPC failure.

Comment: And your question is what? I suggest using the AT syntax to handle this stuff though, perhaps you'll get better performance. Something like: `EXECUTE('delete where FKDAT >= ?', @date) AT MyLinkedServer`

Comment: Getting this error.  Could not execute statement on remote server 'MyLinkedServer'.

Comment: Why don't you just use the linked server directly `DELETE FROM MyLinkedServer..db_from_sap_for_bi.VBRK`